# Node/Feathers with a database in the back

Tags: javascript, node.js, feathersjs

I am learning about Node and Feathers on a job. Need to make a simple app that would use feathers to load the [nedb] with sample data.

```
var fake = require('./fake.js');
var feathers = require('feathers-client');

var io = require('socket.io-client');
var socket = io("http://127.0.0.1:8000");
var app = feathers()
  .configure(feathers.socketio(socket));

var accountsAPIService = app.service('/api/accounts');

var dummyData = fake();

// import dummy data
for ( var i = 0; i < dummyData.accounts.length; i++) {
//  console.log(dummyData.accounts[i]);
  var params =  { query: {}};
  accountsAPIService.create(dummyData.accounts[i], params).then(function(account) {
    console.log("inserted: ", account);
  });
}
// read back inserted records
accountsAPIService.find(params, function(accounts) {
  console.log("accounts: ", accounts);
});
```

i just need to insert items from the array dummyData.accounts into the server.
When I run the script, it seems that nothing is being imported.
When I read the records back, it returns:

```
accounts:  null
```

What is the proper way of inserting/creating records with Feathers?

Comment: my Feathers service is built using FeathersDatabaseAdapter, so I am assuming that create and find are provided by the feathers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could not figure out how to use ".then" so used a regular form:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < dummyData.accounts.length; i++) {
  var params =  { query: {}};
  accountsAPIService.create(dummyData.accounts[i], params, function(error, account) {
//    console.log("inserted: ", account);
  });
}
```

That works fine.
To read the data back, I corrected the method signature. Then, it works. :)

```
accountsAPIService.find(function(error, accounts) {
  console.log("accounts: ", accounts);
});
```

Comment: I'm actually just wrapping up a new version of that adapter that natively supports promises which should make it easier to accomplish it like this:

`Promise.all(dummyData.accounts.map(function(account) {
  return accountsAPIService.create(account);
}).then(function() {
  return accountsAPIService.find(params)
});`